# MongoDb C# driver - test authentication mode

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Using the C# MongoDb driver, is there a way to query a server to find out if it was started with:

`mongod --auth` or just `mongod`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [ticket on the MongoDB tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1677) indicating the [getCmdLineOpts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) command can be used to get the auth mode of the server.

```
db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
```

returns

```
{
  "argv" : [ 
    "mongod", 
    "--config", 
    "mongodb.conf"
  ],
  "parsed" : {
    "auth" : "true",
    "config" : "mongodb.conf",
    ...
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

If `--auth` was passed on the command line it will appear in the `argv` and `parsed` nodes; if it was set in mongodb.conf it will **only** appear in the `parsed` node.